# Why can an address be added to MailMessage.To using object initialisation?

Tags: c#, properties, initialization, c#-7.0

Why or how does the following code work:

```cs
var mail = new MailMessage
{
    To = { "hello@abc.com" }
};
```

given that both `MailMessage.To` is a readonly property, and it is an assignment operator?

As far as I can tell, this syntax triggers the `Add` method on `MailAddressCollection`, but I can't find the documentation that explains this magic for `MailAddressCollection`, or if it relates to either the `Collection<T>` type that it derives or the interfaces it inherits.

To show that the above syntax is being treated differently, the following approaches give compile time errors, complaining that the `To` property is readonly:

```cs
// Attempt 1

var mail = new MailMessage
{
    To = "hello@abc.com"
};

// Attempt 2

var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To = { "hello@abc.com" }

// Attempt 3

var mail = new MailMessage
{
    To = new MailAddressCollection()
};
```

I'm sure there are other examples of this type of initialisation, but `MailMessage` is the first time I have come across it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to answer your questions one at a time

Q1. Why does the code below work?

```
var mail = new MailMessage
{
    To = { "hello@abc.com" }
};
```

A1. The `To` property is essentially a read-only property in which you can only assign a value during object construction.  The "magic" is delivered by Collection Initializer which calls `Add` on types of `IEnumerable` with that syntax.  `MailAddressCollection` is a`Collection<MailAddress>` which in turn implements `IEnumerable`.

As you have deduced, that code is practically equivalent to

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("hello@abc.com");
```

Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Q2. Why doesn't the following codes work?

A2.

```
Attempt1 - you can't assign a string to a collection
Attempt2 - the property is read-only
Attempt3 - the property is read-only
```

Comment: Ok, so it uses the collection initialiser syntax, what I'm not following is how it bypasses the `readonly` aspect of `To`. I thought readonly properties could only be set from the constructor, and object initialiser syntax occurs after the constructor call. Is there any documentation on the initialisation order of steps?

Comment: To is assigned inside the constructor. Take note you arent doing ‘To = new MailAddressCollection {“me@email.com”}’ so you arent violating the readonly modifier